# How do I configure SDK in Android studio

Tags: android

When I open the Android studio it is showing please provide path to Android SDK but I don't have any SDK Packages and folders please anybody help me out to solve this problem

Comment: No I m not getting any proper solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac, then location should be at: `/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk`. Else if you are using Windows, the location should be at `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android`.

If not then you may have to install the SDK, and there are plenty of tutorials online to help you do this, here is one: https://www.androidcentral.com/installing-android-sdk-windows-mac-and-linux-tutorial